# SSRS 2008 R2 / SQL - How to filter groups but keep detail data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

EDIT - i'm reposting this question in an attempt to explain what i mean better

I'm using SQL 2008 R2 and I work for a retail department store and we need a report to show all the sales orders made in each department, and sections of those departments.

What i want is to group up all the sales order lines by department and section, but **remove only the sections that have a total sales value of less than £50**. I still want to see order lines that are over £50, though.

Here is an example of what i currently have:

## Data before filtering

[image]

I want to remove the Accessories section and all lines contained within it, as it has a total section value of less than £50. So i would want it looking like this after filtering:

## Data after filtering

[image]

Here is my code:

```
SELECT      department.department_name
            ,section.section_name
            ,sales_order_detail.sales_order_number
            ,sales_order_detail.sales_order_line
            ,LineValue

FROM
sales_order_detail INNER JOIN stock_item ON sales_order_detail.stock_item_code = stock_item.stock_item_code 
INNER JOIN style ON stock_item.style_code = style.style_code 
INNER JOIN department ON style.dept_code = department.department_code 
INNER JOIN section ON style.section_code = section.section_code AND style.dept_code = section.department_code AND department.department_code = section.department_code
```

Can you please explain all the ways this can be done. I've tried using GROUP BY and HAVING but that then filters out all my sales order lines. I've tried using a Group Filter in the visual studio report design surface which removes the lines but then aggregates calculated at the Department group scope don't take into account the lines removed at the section level.

I appreciate any help i can get on this.
Jacob

Comment: Hello, this box wouldn't let me post all the detail i needed to - i've replied to my own question with the code. Thanks

Comment: I'm using SQL 2008 R2, please see below in my reply to this question for further details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using 2008R2, you can use the magic that are [Windowed Functions](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/) to calculate the total of the group that the row belongs to (the `partition` part of the `over` clause below) and then wrap your query into a filtering `select` statement.  Not having your data this is obviously not tested, but it should work:

```
select department_name
        ,section_name
        ,sales_order_number
        ,sales_order_line
        ,LineValue
        ,GroupTotal
from(
    select d.department_name
            ,se.section_name
            ,sod.sales_order_number
            ,sod.sales_order_line
            ,sod.qty_ordered * sod.selling_price AS LineValue
            ,sum(sod.qty_ordered * sod.selling_price) over (partition by d.department_name
                                                                        ,se.section_name
                                                            ) as GroupTotal

    from sales_order_detail sod
        inner join stock_item si
            on sod.stock_item_code = si.stock_item_code 
        inner join style s
            on stock_item.style_code = s.style_code 
        inner join department d
            on s.dept_code = d.department_code 
        inner join section se
            on s.section_code = se.section_code
                and s.dept_code = se.department_code
                and d.department_code = se.department_code
) a
where GroupTotal > 50
```

Comment: Many thanks Dave. My actual dataset will be returning hundreds of thousands (if not millions) of sales order lines. As that function runs in the SELECT list doesn't that window function run every time for each row? If it has to calculate the same group total 100,000s of times will that not impact our SQL server performance? Just curious as i had thought of windowed functions and discarded it for that reason

Comment: Windowed functions are incredibly efficient at what they do, as they are not the same as regular UDFs.  Regardless of the route you take, in order to filter based on your total, you will by definition have to aggregate across all rows *and then* filter your result.  You could do this with a set of temp tables etc I suppose, but it would require more table reads where Windowed Functions should not.  Performance-wise though I cannot tell you how well this will run in your environment, on that front you will need to do the proper testing yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help - i will take the window function route

Comment: For anyone wondering on performance impact, this has now been tested in live environment and is very efficient.